# Calculate current page base on offset and total

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```
total: 30
limit: 10
offset: 0
current_page: 1

total: 30
limit: 10
offset: 10
current_page: 2

total: 30
limit: 10
offset: 20
current_page: 3
```

What is the formula to get current_page given I have total, limit (item count per page) and offset? Hope I don't misunderstood offset here.

Comment: Could you give examples of `offset` and `total` and the desired output, to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: `Math.floor` instead of `Math.ceil`?

Comment: @Ry︁ added sample data, Math.floor returned zero always

Comment: You need to know the offset and how many items there are per page, not how many items total.

Comment: @Ry︁ oh really? what's the formula if I know the total item per page then?

Comment: I don't see how you can know the current page without using items total @Ry︁

Comment: @Jamie I think you're misunderstanding Ry. (s)He means if items per page is 5, then offset 0 = page 1, offset 5 = page 2, etc.. and you don't need to know total number of pages: pagenumber=offset/5 + 1

Comment: @yezzz I got that now but what's the formula behind it? Also I've edited my question

Comment: Your offsets are only in multiples of the page size? offset / limit + 1

Comment: Did that answer the question? Or maybe you were trying to calculate total number of pages (total/limit)  and then doing some other stuff with it?

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>

function pageNumber(total,limit,offset){
    return offset >= total ? -1 : parseInt(offset / limit) + 1;
}

console.log(pageNumber(30,10,0));
console.log(pageNumber(30,10,10));
console.log(pageNumber(30,10,20));
console.log(pageNumber(30,10,30));

</script>
```

**Output**

```
1
2
3
-1
```